# value error while matching column names

Tags: pandas

The following code shows an error. But it works if I remove usercols parameter.

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

u_cols = ['page_id','web_id']
audit_trail = StringIO('''
page_id | web_id
3|0
7|3
11|4
15|5
19|6
''')

df = pd.read_csv(audit_trail, sep="|", usecols = u_cols  )
```

> ValueError: Passed header names mismatches usecols

I need to use u_cols list because the column headings are being generated dynamically.

Comment: It seems that when I use stringIO, I can not use usercols :)

Answer (score 7):

"names" should be used instead of "usecolmns"

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

u_cols = ['page_id','web_id']
audit_trail = StringIO('''
page_id | web_id
3|0
7|3
11|4
15|5
19|6
''')

df11 = pd.read_csv(audit_trail, sep="|", names = u_cols  )
```

Comment: @DimaLituiev `usecols` specifies which columns, of the ones present, you wish to bring in; the rest will be ignored. `names` specifies how you wish to rename the columns you've chosen to bring in.

Answer (score 3):

This is because of the white space next to the | seperator.  When you run `pd.read_csv(audit_trail,sep="|")` you actually have the columns ['page_id(whitespace)','(whitespace)web_id'] instead of ['page_id','web_id'].

I would suggest passing the following regex pattern as your seperator `\s*\|\s*`, which will remove any whitespace around the | seperator.  Here is the full solution...

```
u_cols = ['page_id','web_id']

"""page_id | web_id
3|0
7|3
11|4
15|5
19|6"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s),sep="\s*\|\s*",usecols = u_cols)
```

**output**

```
   page_id  web_id
0        3       0
1        7       3
2       11       4
3       15       5
4       19       6
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone else tumbles into this error, this is what just happened to me: I used `parse_dates=[[0,1]]` to merge and parse dates from two columns and got this error. So the `names` parameter should contain the same number of columns as the original csv, so I just added and extra empty string in the list: `names=['column1','','column2',...]`.